# form how to get row count of widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-dependencies

[image]
I want to create content for a form that consists of 7 rows. I would like to enter information in Form 1, click 'Next,' proceed to fill out all the subsequent forms, and finally submit my form. How can I use a widget for form entry in this process?

Answer (score 0):

Use Stepper Class

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html

And set its type horizontal

```
Stepper(
      type: StepperType.horizontal,
)
```